# sum of even fibonacci numbers up to 4million

Tags: python, math, fibonacci

The method I've used to try and solve this works but I don't think it's very efficient because as soon as I enter a number that is too large it doesn't work.

```
def fib_even(n):
    fib_even = []
    a, b = 0, 1
    for i in range(0,n):
        c = a+b
        if c%2 == 0:
            fib_even.append(c)
            a, b = b, a+b
return fib_even

def sum_fib_even(n):
    fib_evens = fib_even(n)
    s = 0
    for i in fib_evens:
        s = s+i
    return s

n = 4000000
answer = sum_fib_even(n)
print answer
```

This for example doesn't work for 4000000 but will work for 400. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: In this post, a number of techniques are provided:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172257/efficient-calculation-of-fibonacci-series

Comment: The line `a, b = b, a+b` should be outside the `if` block.

Comment: If that's Project Euler Problem 2, then you've misread it.

Comment: What do you mean with "Doesn't work"? Wrong answer, exception, crash?

Comment: _"The method I've used to try and solve this works"_. Are you sure about that? It just gives me zero for any input I give it. And that's after fixing the bad indentation of `return fib_even`. Can you double check that you formatted your code correctly here?

Comment: Every third Fibonacci number is even, so you could count those. This, incidentally, is the subject of the second question in the Euler Project, https://projecteuler.net/problem=2

Comment: Your code uses a tremendous amount of storage, both because it (unnecessarily) creates the `fib_even` list, which has some very large numbers in it, and in iterating over it while calculating the sum (which is a _huge_ number). In Python number can be any size, and above a certain point, the amount of memory required to do so depends on their magnitude.

Comment: it is allmost impossible not to find solutions to the euler problem 2 here. Look at the related posts

Comment: 4000000-th Fibonacci number has about 835951 digits. As @lhf pointed out you misread the project euler problem 2 question

Comment: To complement the next to last remark, an appropriate query string gives http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=fibonacci%20even%20million%20euler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not necessary to compute all the Fibonacci numbers.

**Note:** I use in what follows the more standard initial values F[0]=0, F[1]=1 for the Fibonacci sequence. Project Euler #2 starts its sequence with F[2]=1,F[3]=2,F[4]=3,.... For this problem the result is the same for either choice.

## Summation of all Fibonacci numbers (as a warm-up)

The recursion equation

```
F[n+1] = F[n] + F[n-1]
```

can also be read as

```
F[n-1] = F[n+1] - F[n]
```

or

```
F[n] = F[n+2] - F[n+1]
```

Summing this up for n from 1 to N (remember F[0]=0, F[1]=1) gives on the left the sum of Fibonacci numbers, and on the right a telescoping sum where all of the inner terms cancel

```
sum(n=1 to N) F[n] = (F[3]-F[2]) + (F[4]-F[3]) + (F[5]-F[4])
                     + ... + (F[N+2]-F[N+1])
                   = F[N+2] - F[2]
```

So for the sum using the number N=4,000,000 of the question one would have just to compute

```
F[4,000,002] - 1
```

with one of the superfast methods for the computation of single Fibonacci numbers. Either halving-and-squaring, equivalent to exponentiation of the iteration matrix, or the exponential formula based on the golden ratio  (computed in the necessary precision).

Since about every 20 Fibonacci numbers you gain 4 additional digits, the final result will consist of about 800000 digits. Better use a data type that can contain all of them.

---

## Summation of the even Fibonacci numbers

Just inspecting the first 10 or 20 Fibonacci numbers reveals that all even members have an index of 3*k. Check by subtracting two successive recursions to get

```
F[n+3]=2*F[n+2]-F[n]
```

so F[n+3] always has the same parity as F[n]. Investing more computation one finds a recursion for members three indices apart as

```
F[n+3] = 4*F[n] + F[n-3]
```

Setting

```
S = sum(k=1 to K) F[3*k]
```

and summing the recursion over n=3*k gives

```
F[3*K+3]+S-F[3] = 4*S + (-F[3*K]+S+F[0])
```

or

```
4*S = (F[3*K]+F[3*K]) - (F[3]+F[0]) = 2*F[3*K+2]-2*F[2]
```

So the desired sum has the formula

```
S = (F[3*K+2]-1)/2
```

A quick calculation with the golden ration formula reveals what N should be so that F[N] is just below the boundary, and thus what K=N div 3 should be,

```
N = Floor(  log( sqrt(5)*Max )/log( 0.5*(1+sqrt(5)) )  )
```

---

## Reduction of the Euler problem to a simple formula

In the original problem, one finds that N=33 and thus the sum is

```
S = (F[35]-1)/2;
```

---

## Reduction of the problem in the question and consequences

Taken the mis-represented problem in the question, N=4,000,000, so K=1,333,333 and the sum is

```
(F[1,333,335]-1)/2
```

which still has about 533,400 digits. And yes, biginteger types can handle such numbers, it just takes time to compute with them.

If printed in the format of 60 lines a 80 digits, this number fills 112 sheets of paper, just to get the idea what the output would look like.

Comment: Python can store integers of virtually any size, limited to the available (and addressable) memory. `4,000,000 / 20 == 200,000`, not `800,000`.

Comment: Yes, 200,000 blocks of 20 Fibonacci numbers, and after each block, the numbers are 4 digits longer, making a total of 800,000 digits. However, the problem was severely misstated, the solution of the original problem only requires all F[3*k] up to F[33] or with a clever formula only F[35].

Answer (score 0):

It should not be necessary to store all intermediate Fibonacci numbers, perhaps the storage causes a performance problem.

Comment: True, but it's only storing the even ones and most computers can easily store a list of up to 4 million numbers. It would also be easy to test your theory, so why didn't you?

Comment: More to the point, storing all the intermediate fibonacci numbers saves them being recomputed multiple times. Storing them is a literal textbook example of making fibonacci more efficient using dynamic programing.