# Using Fibonacci Program to Sum Even Elements

Tags: python, sequence, fibonacci

I am trying to solve the following using Python:

*Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:
1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...*

*By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.*

So far, I have been able to generate the Fibonacci elements but in trying to sum the even elements, my code seems to stall. Here is the code below:

```
def fib(n):
    if n==0:
        return 0
    elif n==1:
        return 1
    if n>1:
        return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)

n=0
total=0

while fib(n)<=4000000:
    if fib(n)%2==0:
        total+=fib(n)

print(total)
```

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: You have an infinite loop, `n` is never incremented up from zero.

Comment: also, dont recalculate recursively for each term like that.  use a generator or something.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Efficient calculation of Fibonacci series](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172257/efficient-calculation-of-fibonacci-series)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an infinite loop as `n` isn't ever incremented up from zero in your `while` loop. Additionally, why not sum your Fibonacci total *as well as* find the next Fibonacci value in the same `while` loop, like this:

```
x= 1
y=1
total = 0
while x <= 4000000:
    if x % 2 == 0:
        total += x
    x, y = y, x + y     
print (total)
```

**Outputs:**

```
4613732
```

Comment: Sorry, I was just about to ask the same question, hence unchecking the answer. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

since this looks like a homework assignment, I threw in some interesting Python

```
from math import sqrt
# Using Binet's formula
def fib(n):
    return int(((1+sqrt(5))**n-(1-sqrt(5))**n)/(2**n*sqrt(5)))

def sum_even_terms(limit = 4000000):
    n = total = 0
    while True:
        term = fib(n)
        n += 1
        if term > limit: break 
        if term % 2 == 0:
            total += term
    return total

print sum_even_terms()

def is_nth_term_even(n):
    return (fib(n) % 2 == 0)

print is_nth_term_even(30)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, here's a really short solution:

```
def fib_even_sum(limit=4*10**6):
    """Sum of the even Fibonacci numbers up to the given limit."""
    b, c = 1, 2
    while c <= limit:
        a = b + c; b = c + a; c = a + b
    return b // 2

print fib_even_sum()  # outputs 4613732
```

It's based on the following facts:

1. Every third Fibonacci number is even.
2. If `Fib(n)` is even, then the sum of the *even* Fibonacci numbers up to `Fib(n)` is equal to the sum of the *odd* Fibonacci numbers up to `Fib(n)` (because each even Fibonacci number is the sum of the two preceding odd Fibonacci numbers).
3. The sum of all Fibonacci numbers (even and odd) up to and including `Fib(n)` is `Fib(n+2) - 1` (via an easy proof by induction).

So if `Fib(n)` is the last even number to be included in the sum, then
the total you want is just `(Fib(n+2) - 1) / 2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a generator and add the numbers

```
def fib():
    a, b = 0, 1
    while 1:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

f = fib()
total = 0
while total <= 4000000:
    current =  f.next()
    if current % 2 == 0:
        total += current

print total
```