# how to find Fibonacci sequence by using python

Tags: python

my code is 80% right but there are 2 tests I cant pass.

here is my code

```
import math
def fib(n):
    a,b = 1,1
    for i in range(n-1):
        a,b = b,a+b
    return a
```

is right when I test fib(100)

but there are one more requirement is time. so here is my test

```
# this should run in less than 5 seconds
print(fib(10 ** 6) % 10 ** 10)
```

is should under 5 second but my code speed like 10sec to run it.

```
# this should run in less than 10 seconds
print(math.floor(math.log10(fib ( 5 * 10 ** 6 ))))
```

so how to improve my code to run these two tests under 10 seconds.

any suggestion will be glad :)

Comment: Please update your test environment. Your machine specs, CPU, RAM etc.

Comment: note the question [efficient calculation of fibonacci series](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172257/efficient-calculation-of-fibonacci-series) has a number of methods and their relative efficiencies.

Comment: There's a non-iterative formular to calculate a number of the Fibonacci sequence. Check the Wikipedia or a similar source.

Comment: Please also take a minute to reformat your question a bit; your code does not run without errors, and the formatting is inconsistent.

Comment: This seems like an odd requirement since speed depends so much on machine specs. Is this a class assignment? Where are the tests being run, on your local computer or some remote server?

Comment: These requirements are very odd.  There is nothing wrong with your `fib` function, but `fib(10**6)` is an over 200,000-digit number in base 10.  All of the time is being spent doing extended-precision integer addition.  I don't really think there are any shortcuts for this.

Comment: Please take a look at the second answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172257/efficient-calculation-of-fibonacci-series