# Python fibonacci series

Tags: python

I wrote a Fibonacci series using Python. Could not figure out why second program is giving wrong answer and first one right when both look same.

Below program gives right answer

```
def fib(n):
  a,b=0,1
  while b<n:
    print b
    a,b=b,a+b

fib(4)
1
1
2
3
```

Below program gives wrong answer:

```
def fib(n):
  a = 0
  b = 1
  while b<n:
    print b
    a = b
    b = a+b

fib(4)

1
2
```

Comment: In second one, you are doing `b = 2*b` actually since `a = b`.

Comment: It's because in the first case `a,b=b,a+b` happens simultaneously and in the second case firstly happens `a=b` and then `b = a+b` is essentially `b = b+b`.

Comment: As a side note, I will give you the benefit of the doubt and assume that your input, `n`, is NOT the number of fibonacci numbers you want printed. Rather it's all fibonacci numbers < `n`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In first one, `a, b = b, a+b` does the assigning simultanously.
In second one, you are first doing `a = b` and then doing `b = a+b` which actually is just `b = 2*b`.

How to achieve such behaviour in second one? Use temporary value to store `a`.

```
def fib(n):
  a = 0
  b = 1
  while b<n:
    print b 
    temp = a
    a = b
    b = temp+b
fib(4)

>>>1
>>>1
>>>2
>>>3
```

Comment: @IronFist BTW, what do you mean by _fix_? Use 4 spaces instead of 2? As long as I am consistent with the number of spaces, I don't think it should be _fixed_.

Comment: According to PEP* (I don't remember what number it was)...Indentation should be 4 spaces...to conform with Coding Style Standard

Comment: PEP-8 is a *recommendation*, which only code in the standard library is required to follow. There's no reason the code here *must* be indented 4 spaces per level, other than to make life easier for people copying it to paste into their own, 4-space-per-level code.

Answer (score 2):

In the second code posted, you redefine the value of b after having changed a, resulting as

```
def fib(n):
  a = 0
  b = 1
while b<n:
  print b     #prints 1
  a = b       #a = 1
  b = a+b     #b = 1 + 1 = 2
```

In the second code, there is no problem, as python code generally reads equations from right to left, thus redefines b first, as is correct

```
def fib(n):
    a,b=0,1    #a = 0, b = 1
while b<n:
    print b
    a,b=b,a+b  #b = 0 + 1 = 1, #a = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

> ### fibonacci series using lambda function in python

```
n = int(input("Enter the range of numbers in fibonacci series:"))
F = [0,1]
list(map(lambda i: F.append(F[i-1] + F[i-2]), range(2, n)))
print(F)
```

Answer (score 2):

### fibonacci series using List Comprehension function in python

```
n = int(input("Enter the range of numbers in fibonacci series:"))
F = [0,1]
[F.append(F[i-1] + F[i-2]) for i in range(2,n)]
print(F)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, you've used this code:

```
a,b=b,a+b
```

While in the second, you've done this instead:

```
a = b
b = a+b
```

These are *not* the same thing.

For the sake of argument, let's say that `a = 3` and `b = 6`. Let's run the working code first:

```
>>> a, b = 10, a + 1
>>> a
10
>>> b
4
```

The value of `a + 1` is 4 rather than 11, because `b`'s assignment is using the *old* value of `a`, so `3 + 1 == 4`.

Now let's put `a` and `b` back to their starting values. Let's try the other method of assigning:

```
>>> a = 10
>>> b = a + 1
>>> a
10
>>> b
11
```

Now `b` is 11! That's because `a` was assigned *before* the assignment of `b`, so the addition uses `a`'s *new* value.

The reason your second version isn't working is because the assignments don't happen simultaneously, so `b` is actually `2 * b` because `a` has already been set to `b` by the time `a+b` is executed.

Answer (score 0):

```
def fibonacci (n):
    if n == 1 or n == 2:
        return 1
    return fibonacci (n-1) + fibonacci (n-2)

for i in range(1,50):
    print (fibonacci(i))
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: This doesn't even try to address the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
n1 = 0
n2 = 1
c = 0

nTerms = int(input())

if nTerms <= 0:
    print("Enter the valid value")
elif nTerms == 1:
    print(a)
else:
    while c < nTerms:
        print(n1)
        nth = n1 + n2
        n1 = n2
        n2 = nth
        c += 1
```

Comment: The question is seeking an explanation of what is going wrong. Please explain what is wrong with the code that is not working.

Answer (score 0):

## Fibonacci Series Using Recursion

```
def f_recursion(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return n
    else:
        return(f_recursion(n-1) + f_recursion(n-2))
# Driver Code
nterms = int(input())
if nterms <= 0:
    print("Enter the positive value")
else:
    for i in range(0,nterms):
        print (f_recursion(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n1=int(input("Enter Term"))
mylist=[0,1]
for a in range(n1):
    sum=0
    for b in mylist[len(mylist)-2:]:
        sum+=b
    mylist.append(sum)
print(mylist)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

```
def fib(n):
    a=0
    b=1
    sum=0
    for i in range(0,n):
        print(sum)
        sum = a + b 
        b = a
        a = sum
fib(10) // here you can add any n value from 1 to 100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# The below code will generate the fibonacci series as per desired range
# just put the number, you want the fibonaci series upto.

def fibonacci(num):
    x,y = 0,1
    if num==1:
        print(x)
    elif num==2:
        print(x,y)
    else:
        print(x,y,end = " ")
        for i in range(num-2):
            z=x+y
            x=y
            y=z
            print(z,end = " ")
```

Comment: This doesn't really address OP's question why their code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following simple approach based on the **simplified** version of the [Binet formula](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Applied_Mathematics/Book%3A_College_Mathematics_for_Everyday_Life_(Inigo_et_al)/10%3A_Geometric_Symmetry_and_the_Golden_Ratio/10.04%3A_Fibonacci_Numbers_and_the_Golden_Ratio):

```
F(n) = (((1+SQRT(5))/2)^n)/SQRT(5)
```

which can be expressed in Python as follows:

```
import math
def fibo(n):
    return (round((((1+math.sqrt(5))/2)**n)/math.sqrt(5),0))
```

and to return the series for the first `10` Fibonacci numbers:

```
print([int(fibo(n)) for n in range(1,11)])
```

The following is an efficient way to generate a Fibonacci *series*:

```
def fib_seq(n):
    seq = [1,1]
    for i in range(2, n):
        seq.append(seq[-1] + seq[-2])
    return 1 if n <= 1 else seq
```

Here is the output
[image: output]

**Note**: Based on the following post: [Efficient calculation of Fibonacci series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172257/efficient-calculation-of-fibonacci-series/32215743#32215743). Python starting from Fibonacci number 72, the first formula doesn't provide the correct result (probably related to Python numeric precision, because testing in Excel gives the correct result). Then the following formula can be used:

```
def fibo(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for i in range(n):
        a, b = b, a + b
    return a
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def fib(n1, n2):
    print(n1)
    print(n2)
    for i in range(n1, n2):
        n1 += n2
        n2 += n1
        print(n1)
        print(n2)

starting_number = int(input('Enter First Term: '))
ending_number = int(input('Enter Second Number: '))
fib(starting_number, ending_number)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour]. SO isn't for sharing various implementations of code, it's for answering questions. OP asks why _their_ version doesn't work. A totally new implementation doesn't answer that question.