# Python: Calculate the last digit of a large Fibonacci Number with less time

Tags: python-3.x, fibonacci

```
# Uses python3

# Compute the Last Digit of a Large Fibonacci Number
def Fib_Last_Digit(n):

    if n == 0 : return 0
    elif n == 1: return 1
    else:

        a,b = 0,1
        for i in range(1,n):
            c = a + b;
            a = b;
            b = c;
        # Calculate the last digit of the final number 
        lastdigit = int(repr(c)[-1]);
        print(lastdigit);

n = int(input(""));
Fib_Last_Digit(n);
```

This code works very well. However, I want to revise the algorithm to save more time and memory. By the way, the input and output should be kept the same with the previous version.

Comment: To get the last digit, you might as well do modulo 10: `lastdigit = c % 10`

Comment: I try this way. However, when n is given as 999999, the calculation takes as much time as the previous one.

Comment: You can modulo 10 during the calculation as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172257/efficient-calculation-of-fibonacci-series

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only keeping the last digit during calculation saves a lot of time:

```
def fib_last_digit(n):
    if n < 2: return n
    else:
        a, b = 0, 1
        for i in range(1,n):
            a, b = b, (a+b) % 10
        print(b)

n = int(input())
fib_last_digit(n)
```

Handling numbers that fit in fewer bytes saves time.

When you're working with huge numbers, you can save a *lot* of time using the answer described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23462371/1016216), slightly modified to only keep track of the last digit:

```
def fib_last_digit(n):
    v1, v2, v3 = 1, 1, 0    # initialise a matrix [[1,1],[1,0]]
    for rec in bin(n)[3:]:  # perform fast exponentiation of the matrix (quickly raise it to the nth power)
        calc = (v2*v2) % 10
        v1, v2, v3 = (v1*v1+calc) % 10, ((v1+v3)*v2) % 10, (calc+v3*v3) % 10
        if rec == '1': v1, v2, v3 = (v1+v2) % 10, v1, v2
    return v2
```

And finally, based on the concept described in Eugene Yarmash's answer (the last digits repeat every 60 steps) we can make an even faster solution (O(1)):

```
def fib_last_digit(n):
    return (
        [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 3, 1, 4, 5, 9, 4, 3, 7, 0, 7, 7, 4, 1, 5, 6, 1, 7, 8, 5, 3, 8, 1, 9, 0, 9, 9, 8, 7, 5, 2, 7, 9, 6, 5, 1, 6, 7, 3, 0, 3, 3, 6, 9, 5, 4, 9, 3, 2, 5, 7, 2, 9, 1, 0]
        [n % 60 - 1]
    )
```

Comment: Awesome. Very helpful answer!

Comment: I have another question: When I change modulo 10 to modulo m (any positive integer) and run a case as n = 99999999999999999, m = 2, it takes me much time. Do you have any good solutions?

Comment: I added a superfast solution stolen from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23462371/1016216).

Answer (score 4):

The series of final digits of Fibonacci numbers [repeats](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/113536) with a cycle length of 60. Therefore, the `N`th Fibonacci number has the same last digit as the `(N % 60)`th, which should be pretty fast to calculate. As an additional optimization, you can keep only the last digit of each term:

```
def fib_last_digit(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for i in range(n % 60):
        a, b = b, (a + b) % 10
    return a    

print([fib_last_digit(n) for n in range(1, 11)])
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 3, 1, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def fib(n): 
    phi = (1 + 5 ** 0.5) / 2
    fib_n = round(((phi** n) - (phi**-n) )/(5 ** .5))
    return fib_n % 10
```

Phi is your friend.

Comment: Doesn't work with very large numbers (`OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')`)

Answer (score 0):

```
def fib_digit(n):
    f=[1,1]
    for i in range(2,n):
        f.append((f[i-1]+f[i-2])  % 10 ) 
    return f[-1]

n = int(input())
print(fib_digit(n))
```

This is one of the simplest answers,i'm sure, there is a faster algorithm.

Here is what I found:

```
f1, f2 = 0, 1
for i in range(int(input())-1):
    f1, f2 = f2, (f1+f2)%10
print(f2)
```

Answer (score 0):

It took only --- 0.002832174301147461 seconds --- to complete the code.

```
import time
n = 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000


def printfib(previous, latest, n):
    if(latest > n):
        return
    print(', ', latest, end='')
    printfib(latest, previous + latest, n)


start_time = time.time()
print(0, end='')
printfib(0, 1, n)
print(" ")
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```