# can you output a Fibonacci sequence with one variable?

Tags: python

Hey I am trying to get a Fibonacci sequence to output with a single variable in the mix. normally if I was using 2 variables I would have it set up like this:

```
nmbr1 = nmbr2 = 1
while nmbr1 < 100:
  nmbr1, nmbr2 = nmbr1 + nmbr2, nmbr1
  print (nmbr1)
```

but how would I get it complete the sequence with only one variable in python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since nobody mentioned *what* sort of object the variable should be, here's using a `list` ;-)

```
x = [1, 1]

while x[0] < 100:
     x = x[1], sum(x)
     print(x[0])

1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
144
```

---

If you *really* want to be sneaky, you can use the [closed form solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression) for the Fibonacci series by approximation with the golden ratio.

```
def fib(n): 
    return int((((1 + 5 ** .5) / 2) ** n) / (5 ** .5) + .5)

f = c = 1
while f < 100:
    c += 1
    f = fib(c) 
    print(f)

1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
144
```

This only uses one variable - `n` - and it calculates *`F[n]`* in constant time. Run a loop and keep calling `fib` successively.

Comment: @JoranBeasley I've upvoted yours since it is most likely what they're looking for :)

Comment: unfortunately i can only assume its for some homework or something ... and i dont think they necessarily want all fibs under one 100 but rather the 100th fib

Comment: @JoranBeasley It very well may be... although the question doesn't explicitly mention what exactly op is trying to compute... the `while nmbr1 < 100` in their Q may say otherwise... though we'll just have to wait...

Comment: Why `x[:]` instead of just `x`?

Comment: @StefanPochmann I wanted to use the same list object instead of recreating it in each iteration (so it looks more like what OP wants).

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "variable" then. Either way I see only one variable there, namely `x`.

Answer (score 3):

```
def fib(n):
    if n <= 2: return 1
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

print fib(12) # the 12th fibinocci number
```

maybe ... it works a bit different then yours and it will fall apart with big numbers probably

Comment: its sort of a trap ... from an employers standpoint this is likely to not get you the job, since it slows down alot as you get to bigger numbers(try to get the 100th fibinocci for example)

Comment: Perfectly at home on a website called Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting solution. The memoization component is courtesy of [Efficient calculation of Fibonacci series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172257/efficient-calculation-of-fibonacci-series).

```
import functools

@functools.lru_cache(None)
def fib(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

def fib_yield(n):
    for i in range(n):
        yield fib(i)

list(fib_yield(10))  # [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
```

Answer (score 1):

yes definitely agree with @joran-beasley

fastest and advanced technique for this is Memoization technique, though it is complicated. Memoization avoids computing already computed values by storing them, here we can store it in the dictionary with its positions as keys.

I learnt this from a very old answer in SO https://stackoverflow.com/a/18172463/5334188

Comment: Nope, memoization is only quadratic in time. My second answer does it in linear using the closed form ;)

Comment: Upvoted yours too, but you may want to edit your answer for a little more detail ;)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ How is memoization only quadratic in time?