# Why fibonacci calculation stuck for value > 35

Tags: python-3.x, infinite-loop

I was doing a basic implementation of fibonacci series in **python3**. Currently I am not thinking about the optimization but the basic output.
The case is, the program gets stuck at some point for the value >35 or something.

I really want to know **what causing this** long calculating time issue?

I have already tried the **dynamic programming** way, that **works fine** for larger values too. I have also implemented that in **C** but no solution. In case of memory storage, it's also not a very big thing to store or process.

```py
def fibonacci_recursive(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fibonacci_recursive(n-1)  + fibonacci_recursive(n-2)

print(fibonacci_recursive(45))
```

Without showing any kind of error, the program get deeper and deeper of recursion.

Comment: It's not an infinite loop; it just takes a very long time to complete.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172257/efficient-calculation-of-fibonacci-series

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficient calculation of Fibonacci series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172257/efficient-calculation-of-fibonacci-series)

Comment: Thanks for addressing the duplicate question. Exactly what I needed to know.