# Even valued terms sum in fibonacci, limit is 4 million

Tags: python, fibonacci

```
def fib(n):
   if n<= 1: 
       return n 
   else: 
       return(fib(n-1)+fib(n-2))

def comp():
   L=[]
   for i in range(1,4000000): 
        if i % 2 ==0:
           L.append(fib(i))
           return sum(L)
print(comp())
```

What is wrong with this code? It does not return anything but it looks good according to me.

Comment: fib itself taking more times, optimization of fibonacci will work, you can take example https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/examples/fibonacci-sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should return `sum(L)` from function not from for loop follow below code

```
def fib(n):
    if n<= 1: 
        return n 
    else: 
        return(fib(n-1)+fib(n-2))

def comp():
    L=[]
    for i in range(1,20): 
        if i % 2 ==0:
            L.append(fib(i))
    return sum(L)

print(comp())
```

and other thing look at the range its too much,because of this it will take some time or may produce any memory related error, so reduce it for testing.

Comment: Thank you! It worked but really slow for the big numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The `return` statement is set to the wrong increment. It is executed the first time `i % 2 == 0` becomes true (which is i == 2 in your case).

```
def fib(n):
   if n<= 1: 
       return n 
   else: 
       return(fib(n-1)+fib(n-2))

def comp():
   L=[]
   for i in range(1,4000000): 
        if i % 2 ==0:
           L.append(fib(i))
   return sum(L)

print(comp())
```

The above code is not going to work, though. Are you aware of how big this number would get?

Try

```
for i in range(1,40):
```

as a start. It took quite a few seconds on my machine. Result is 63245985.

Comment: Oh, I see. It worked but is not efficient. Do you have any ideas to make it fast? Thank you.

Comment: Here are some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172257/efficient-calculation-of-fibonacci-series