# Fibonacci Sequence using Python

Tags: python, while-loop, anaconda, fibonacci

Hello I am trying to write a script that prompts the user for an integer number (n), then prints all the Fibonacci numbers that are less than or equal to the input, in that order.
EXAMPLE:

Enter a number : 14

output is: 1 1 2 3 5 8 13

Here is what i have so far but not sure if it is the most efficient way? It is working correctly but I was wondering if there is a easier way to clean this up..

```
n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
a = 0
b = 1
sum = 0


while(sum <= n):
 print(sum, end = " ")
 count += 1
 a = b
 b = sum 
 sum = a + b

print(end = " ")
```

I am fairly new to python and am doing some practice but was not able to find a solution in textbook.

Comment: As is, that doesnt even run. It also prints 0 first

Comment: It's clean enough, as below answer, declaring only 2 variables without `sum` is not a best practice for coding convention.

Comment: I found this one that can help you: [Look for the bottom-up approach in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172257/efficient-calculation-of-fibonacci-series)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way is efficient enough, but your code can do better

```
n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
a = b = 1

while(b <= n):
 print(b, end = " ")
 a, b = b, a + b
```

Comment: https://leetcode.com/problems/climbing-stairs/, You can check the solutions to this question

Answer (score 1):

Someting like this?

```
n = int(input("Enter a number: "))

fib = [0, 1]
while fib[-1] + fib[-2] <= n:
    fib.append(fib[-1] + fib[-2])

print(fib)
```

It depends on what you mean by "most efficieny way".
Fibonacci is a fairly typical coding exercise, most of the time used to explain recursion. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/499245/14737723) for example.

Comment: You are conducting add values 2 times, which is not very optimized at all.

Comment: Yes, storing that sum could lead to some improvement. Printing to screen inside the loop is not good either, that's why I proposed storing the sequence in a list.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really like the the approaches above, as number sequences are **infinite** and **memory allocation** is not. Thus in order to effectively get the highest possibly computable numbers (by your computer of course), one should definetly use **generators.**

```
ITERATIONS = 100
def fibo():
     a, b = 0, 1
    
     while True:
         a, b = b, a + b
         yield b

f = fibo()

for _ in range(ITERATIONS):
     print(next(f))
```

**!** But please bear in mind, that your computer will **100% crash** if you attempt something like `list(f)` as the number sequence is infinite, and your computer power & storage is not.

Have a good one.

Answer (score 0):

I give thanks to tboschi. His code helped me solve this question.

```
# fibonacci_list = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, ...]
fibonacci_list = [0, 1]
for value in fibonacci_list:
    if value < 1000000:
        new_value = fibonacci_list[-1] + fibonacci_list[-2]
        fibonacci_list.append(new_value)

def fibonacci(n):
    # Type your code here. 
    if n >= 0: 
        for index_num in range(len(fibonacci_list)):
            if n == index_num:
                return fibonacci_list[index_num]
    else:
        return -1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_num = int(input())
    print('fibonacci({}) is {}'.format(start_num, fibonacci(start_num)))
```