# program to find fibonacci sequence of a number

Tags: python, python-3.x

how do i find the fibonacci sequence of a number . Here Is The code

```
def fib(n):
    for i in range(n):
        b = 1 
        
        b+=i
        print(b)
        
p = fib(9)
```

the program just returns the normal sum. how to do this in the easy way

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficient calculation of Fibonacci series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172257/efficient-calculation-of-fibonacci-series)

Comment: You're setting `b` to 1 in each iteration of the loop, rather than taking into account the new, updated `b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this using recursion

```
def fibonacci(n):
  if n <= 0:
    return 0
  elif n == 1:
    return 1
  else:
    return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
```

Answer (score 3):

The fibonacci sequence is built by adding the last two values of the sequence, starting with 1,1 (or 0,1 for the modern version).  A recursive function does it elegantly:

```
def fib(n,a=1,b=1): 
    return a if n==1 else fib(n-1,b,a+b)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
n = 10
a, b = 0, 1
while a <= n:
    print(a)
    a, b = b, a + b
```

Comment: This prints fib numbers less than n, not the first n numbers.  This is however a good general technique