# My homework is to find out the line by line explanation of this code

Tags: python

When i run this code it doesn't have an output, and please can you explain the purpose of this code and give a line-by-line explanation of how it achieves its purpose.

```
def mystery(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    while a < n
       print (a)
       a, b = b, a + b
```

I have also figured out how to make it output
You add a line which is mystery(n) e.g. mystery(200)

I think it is like this:

• The first line defines a function with one parameter. The word “def” presents a function
  definition. The function “def” must be followed by the function name e.g. mystery.

• The second line contains a multiple assignment. It is saying that the variable “a” is equal 
  to 0 and “b” is equal to 1

• The function defines the value of “n”. On the third line “n” is undefined.

• The fourth line is to print (a)

• The fifth line makes

Comment: Run the code. Notice the first few numbers it outputs. Put that in google. Enjoy ;)

Comment: it is  a Fibonacci algo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15047116/a-iterative-algorithm-for-fibonacci-numbers

Comment: We had the same question here with the same mistake (a should be 1 initially not 0) some days ago. I just can't find it at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

This code is a **Fibonacci series** generator upto `n`. The only error is the missing colon (`:`) after `while` statement. It starts with `a=0` abd `b=1`: compares `a < n`; `prints a` if comparison generates `True`; assigns `b to a` and increments `b by a`; continues `while` loop until comparison generates `False`:

```
>>> def mystery(n):
...     a, b = 0, 1
...     while a < n:
...        print (a)
...        a,b = b,a+b
... 
>>> mystery (10)
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# This is a method. 
# You can call this method to its logic. (sea last line)
# N would be the maximum value
def mystery(n):
    # This is the same as:
    # a = 0 Asign a to 0
    # b = 1 Asign b to 1
    a, b = 0, 1
    # Do the following until a is the same or bigger than n.
    while a < n:
       # Print the value of a
       print a
        # This is the same as:
        # temp = a
        # a = b
        # b = a + b
        # Example: a =1 and b =2
        # temp = a
        # a = 2
        # b = temp + 2
       a, b = b, a + b
# Calling the method with value 10
# you first have to call this before it executes
mystery(10)
```

Output:

```
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
```

This is called fibonacci

Comment: `a, b = b, a + b` is more something like this: `tmp = a` followed by `a = b` and then `b = tmp + b`

Comment: actually, it isn't a method, its a function

Comment: Lets not confuse the OP. I don't think it matters, whether we call it a method or a function. But you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining the value you want the Fibonacci sequence for inside of the code, why not change the code to:

```
def mystery(n):
   a, b = 0, 1
   while a < n:
      print (a)
      a, b = b, a + b
mystery(int(input("Insert A Number: ")))
```

This will allow the user to input a value of which, the Fibonacci sequence will be shown.