# Find the nth element in a tribonacci series

Tags: c#

I found this as a [Microsoft interview question (see Round 4)](http://www.crazyforcode.com/microsoft-interview-questions-internship-set-4/). I am trying to solve it using C#. My attempt:

```
private static int NTerm_Tribonacci(int term)
        {
            int a = 0;
            int b = 1;
            int c = 1;
            int result = 0;
            if (term == 1) return a;
            if (term == 2) return b;
            if (term == 3) return c;

            for (int i = 4; i <= term; i++)
            {
                a = a + b + c; if ((1 + 3 * i) % term == 0) { result = a; break; }
                b = a + b + c; if ((2 * i + i - 1) % term == 0) { result = b; break; }
                c = a + b + c; if ((3 * i) % term == 0) { result = c; break; }
            }
            return result;           
        }
```

But it is somehow not working  `var res = NTerm_Tribonacci(5);`//should be 4 but getting 44

How can I solve this?

[Tribonacci Number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TribonacciNumber.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
private static int NTerm_Tribonacci(int term)
    {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 1;
        int c = 1;
        int result = 0;

        if (term == 0) result = a;
        if (term == 1) result = b;
        if (term == 2) result = c;

        while(term > 2)
        {
            result = a + b + c;
            a = b;
            b = c;
            c = result;
            term--;
        }

        return result;           
    }
```

Note that as per the definition in your link, I have assumed the first term to be T0, not T1.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/CYHNT79850)

Comment: So it does. Please check the demo link I have posted.

Comment: From the definition: "The first few terms for n=0, 1, 2, ... are 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 7, 13, 24, 44, 81, 149," So if I call the index of my first term zero, then term five will be 7 and not 4. If you really want to call the first term term 1 rather than term 0, just increment the numbers as required.

Answer (score 1):

I like the "LINQ way" of solving such things:

```
    public IEnumerable<long> InfiniteTribonacciSequence()
    {
        long a = 0, b = 1, c = 1;
        long nextTerm;

        yield return a;
        yield return b;
        yield return c;

        while (true)
        {
            nextTerm = a + b + c;
            yield return nextTerm;

            a = b;
            b = c;
            c = nextTerm;
        }
    }
```

But this has to be used carefully, because Methods like `Min()` will go crazy with this. But you can use e.g. `InfiniteTribonacciSequence.Take(5).Last()` to get the 5th element of the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I think the recursive way is too suitable for such cases:

example:

```
using System.IO;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

        int a=4, b;
        b=tribo(a);
        Console.WriteLine(b);
    }

    static public int tribo(int n)
    {
        if(n==0) return 0;
        if(n==1) return 1;
        if(n==2) return 1;
        return(tribo(n-1)+tribo(n-2)+tribo(n-3));
    }
}
```

this gives the series 0 1 1 2 4 7 13 24 ...

Comment: I think a recursive solution is not optimal in a language like C# or Java. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21710756/recursion-vs-iteration-fibonacci-sequence

Comment: sorry for the word *suitable*, but I think even *optimal* is not required by the OP, just a working code is sufficient

Comment: Fibonacci is commonly used to show the pitfalls of a simple recursive solution and to introduce memoization as a concept - the only real issue with recursive solutions in C# is that the compiler doesn't support tail call optimization in places that it could, but the common recursive Fibonacci solution isn't tail recursive anyhow. It does, however, hugely benefit from memoization for an n of fairly small magnitude or greater.