# Fibonacci Recursive function takes forever

Tags: recursion, fortran, fibonacci

I want to get the 48th element of the Fibonacci sequence
which I can store in a 64 bit integer. I am using a recursive subroutine, but it is taking forever to finish. If anyone can find a problem with my recursive subroutine, I would be very grateful.

```
Integer (Int8) :: n
Integer (Int64) :: fib64
n = Int (48, Int8)
Call fibonacci_genr (fib64, n)
```

Here is my recursive subroutine

```
Recursive                  &
Subroutine fibonacci_genr  &
(                        &
  fb, n                  &
)

Integer (Int64), Intent (Out) :: fb
Integer (Int8), Intent (In) :: n

    Integer (Int64) :: fb1, fb2
    If (n < 2) Then 
      fb = Int (n, Int64) 
    Else 
      Call fibonacci_genr (fb1, n-1)
      Call fibonacci_genr (fb2, n-2)
      fb = fb1 + fb2
    End If
End Subroutine fibonacci_genr
```

Comment: Have you worked out how many calls are needed to compute the 48th fibonacci number recursively?  (Hint: a lot)

Comment: just put counter in your subroutine and count # of calls and print it - you'll be enlightened.

Comment: You could memorize your answers no need to look it up twice.

Comment: The number of calls is phenomenal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appologies I don't know fortran I'll try my best to show you how to speed it up in javascript and my best at a fortran solution

```
var memo = [];
function fib(n) {
    if (memo[n-1]) { //check to see if you already calculated the answer
        return memo[n-1];
    }
    memo[n-1] = n <= 1 ? 1 : fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
    return memo[n-1];
}
```

Here is the memoized fortran

```
Integer (Int64) :: memo(48) = 0

Integer (Int64), Intent (Out) :: fb
Integer (Int8), Intent (In) :: n

Integer (Int64) :: fb1, fb2
If (memo(n) > 1) Then    ! if its in the array we just use that value
    fb = memo(n)
Else If (n <= 2) Then 
    memo(n) = Int (1, Int64) 
    fb = memo(n)
Else 
    Call fibonacci_genr (fb1, n-1)
    Call fibonacci_genr (fb2, n-2)
    memo(n) = fb1 + fb2
    fb = memo(n)
End If
End Subroutine fibonacci_genr
```

Comment: Does there exist a solution which does not need to store all the fibonacci numbers?

Comment: @Zeus So this trades computation time for space. I'm pretty sure you need a way to "remember" the old values if you don't want to calculate them each time. If space is an issue you could adjust it to only remember every 10 fib numbers or so. Then it would calculate on average the last 5 fib numbers.

Comment: @Zeus if you can store the numbers this would be MUCH faster.

Comment: I found I can use the golden ratio

Comment: @Zeus OH YEAH you can calculate fib numbers in constant space and time with a funny equation

Comment: `Integer (Int64) :: memo(48)` in the subroutine doesn't make a global array and it isn't initialized to anything.  You could use `Integer (Int64) :: memo(48)=0` which does initialize the local array in the subroutine and also makes it a _saved_ variable.  If that declaration was meant to be outside the subroutine, then its accessibility inside will depend on things, but it will still need some form of initial setting to 0.

Comment: Cool thanks. I wasn't sure on the initialization syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Given that `Int8=1` and `Int64=8` and explicit interface, gfortran4.7.2 complains that

```
call fibonacci_genr( fb1, n-1 )
                          1
Error: Type mismatch in argument 'n' at (1); passed INTEGER(4) to INTEGER(1)
```

If the actual arguments are cast to `Int8`

```
Call fibonacci_genr (fb1, int( n-1, Int8 ) )
```

or `Int8` literals are used directly (thanks to @francescalus)

```
Call fibonacci_genr (fb1, n - 1_Int8 )
```

the code seems to work fine. But I think it is much simpler to use `integer :: n`  rather than `integer(Int8) :: n` because there is no overflow for `n`....

BTW I also measured the time for calling this routine for `n = 0` to `48`. It was 91 sec on Xeon2.6GHz(x86_64) + gfortran4.7.2 -O2. The time reduced to 72 sec if the subroutine is replaced by a function. For comparison, I also tried the following code in Julia

```
function fibo( n::Int )  # Int defaults to Int64
    if n <= 1
        return n
    else
        return fibo( n-1 ) + fibo( n-2 )
    end
end

for inp = 0:48
    println( fibo( inp ) )
end
```

took 118 sec and so pretty good for this recursion. On the other hand, direct iteration (without recursive calls) is of course superfast and takes only <0.001 sec.

Comment: You do not get the problem using Fortran-5.

Comment: @Zeus What's Fortran-5?

Comment: gfortran-5 is the latest version of gfortran

Comment: Ah, okay. Unfortunately, I am still using gfortran-4 (up to 4.8.2). BTW I googled for Fortran-5 and immediately found this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran_5  Hmm..

Comment: In the Julia version, you can, I think, even leave out the `::Int` declaration, since it's a type stable function; it runs in the same time as when you include it.

Comment: @daycaster Thanks, I have just confirmed that changing `n::Int` to `n` do not change the speed at all. But I am still not very sure how to judge a function is "type stable". In simple cases, if dummy arguments are used only as r-values, one may not need to attach type assert (or annotation), but it seems not clear how to judge it in more complicated situations. I will search for more documents about this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This solution gives you a fibonacci digit in linear time (# of calls == fibonacci digit -2, and only 1 call for digits 1 and 2).  This is accomplished by using a recursive function that returns two digits of the sequence so that each call can calculate the next digit and re-use the previous digit as its return values.  This does require a wrapper function if you want to call it to receive only the new digit, but this is a small sacrifice for reduced recursion.

Here are the functions:

```
  integer(kind=int64) pure function fibonacci(n)
    use iso_fortran_env
    implicit none
    integer, intent(in) :: n
    integer(kind=int64), dimension(2) :: fibo

    fibo = fib(int(n,int64))
    fibonacci = fibo(1)
  end function fibonacci

  recursive pure function fib(n) result(ret)
    use iso_fortran_env
    implicit none
    integer(kind=int64), intent(in) :: n
    integer(kind=int64), dimension(2) :: tmp,ret

    if (n == 1_int64) then
       ret = [1_int64, 0_int64]
    else if (n == 2_int64) then
       ret = [1_int64, 1_int64]
    else
       tmp = fib(n-1)
       ret = [sum(tmp), tmp(1)]
    end if
  end function fib
```

Using these functions the time to calculate `fibonacci(48)` is negligible.

Answer (score 0):

Calculating Fibonacci recursively like this leads to repeated calculations [Recursion vs. Iteration (Fibonacci sequence)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21710756/recursion-vs-iteration-fibonacci-sequence) .  To avoid this, use an iterative algorithm.

Comment: It is what I am encountering

Answer (score 0):

This is written in Python (again no FORTRAN).

```
def f(a):
  if (a < 2):
    return a;
  return _f(a-2, 2, 1)

def _f(a, n1 , n2) :
  if(a==0) :
    return n1+n2
  return _f(a-1, n1+n2, n1)
```

Each number is only calculated once instead of multiple times. _f is a private function f is the one you call,

Note: this is still recursive but will only call itself 48 times (order N)

Comment: Have i missed something? What is wrong with my answer? I don't have enough rep to comment on other posts. But you don't need to cache all the values in a array,